# Probability of throwing every throw is larger than the previous one for a dice.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there is a 10 sided die, and we throw it 5 times.

Then, to obtain each throwing being larger than the previous one, the first roll must be less than or equal to $6$.

If $6$ is the first roll, then the only possibility is $6 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 9 \rightarrow 10$

If 5 is the first roll, then the we have $4$ possibilities:

$5 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 9 \rightarrow 10$

$5 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 9 \rightarrow 10$

$5 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 9 \rightarrow 10$

$5 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 9$

I have tried this for when the first roll is $4$, and there are $10$ possibilities.

I can't seem to find a pattern and I am stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you after the _probability_ that each throw is larger than the previous?

Comment: @Arthur ultimately I am. I know how to get the sample space, so I am currently concerned with obtaining the number of possible events that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I see you missed one, by the way. (As did I, so you can see how difficult this is): $5\to6\to7\to8\to10$. So the count is $5$ possibilities starting with $5$. Presumably, this means that there are $15$ that start with $4$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and great catch!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take a look at Pascal's triangle. Can you find a nice and simple $1,5, 15$ pattern somewhere? What do you think comes next?

Completely different hint: For the die throws to come out with each one larger than the last, two things need to happen: First, each throw has to be different. Second, given that they are all different, they need to come in a specific order.

---

Let's count the number of possibilities that start with 3 in a way that hopefully illuminates how the binomial coefficients (the numbers in Pascal's triangle) appear. Have a die next to you (or imagine one if you don't have one). Start with it showing 3, and write down $3\to$.

Now, a total of seven times, choose between

- Increase the die by 1, then write down the number on the die
- Just increase the number on the die by 1

in some order. This way the die ultimately ends up at 10. You have to choose the top alternative four times, as that is what you need to get five die results in total. Thus the number of sequences starting with $3$ is $\binom74 = 35$.

Note that you can use this exact approach to count the total number of sequences without dividing into cases: Start with the die "showing" $0$, and with nothing written down. Then choose between the two alternatives a total of 10 times in some order. Five of the choices have to be the top alternative.

Comment: I figured that when the first roll is $3$, there are $20$ possibilities. I guess $20$ shows up in the next row of the pascal's triangle, but I don't quite understand the pattern behind the answer unless I am still missing something.

Comment: @K.Hu.1106 I added an explanation.

Comment: Your second paragraph seemed to be leading towards the simple solution in my answer. But then you didn't use your own hint!

Comment: @TonyK I said that's a hint for a completely different solution. The workings-out was added after the fact, using the first hint. Did you want me to try to shoehorn the second hint into the solution I wrote somehow? That's not going to be pretty.

Answer (score 1):

When the first number is $6$, there are $4$ numbers remaining and you select $4$ numbers in one way:
$$6<7<8<9<10 \Rightarrow {4\choose 4}=1.$$
When the first number is $5$, there are $5$ numbers remaining and you select $4$ numbers in $5$ ways:
$$5<6<7<8<9<10 \Rightarrow {5\choose 4}=5$$
When the first number is $4$, there are $6$ numbers remaining and you select $4$ numbers in $15$ ways:
$$4<5<6<7<8<9<10 \Rightarrow {6\choose 4}=15$$
Do you see the pattern? Can you find the number of ways when the first number is $2$ for example?

Answer:

> $${8\choose 4}=70.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Your solution does follow the pattern. I would like to understand the logic behind the binomial coefficient though. I understand why we "choose 4" because we have 4 more rolls after the 1st roll.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is the [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). Unlike permutation, in combination, the order of selection does not matter. For example, if the first number is $5$ and $5$ numbers are remaining. You need to select $4$ out of the remaining $5$ numbers. There are ${5\choose 4}=5$ ways to select $4$ out of $5$ numbers when the order does not matter. For every selection, you can then put them in increasing order.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10^5$ possible sequences of throws. Of these, there are $10\times 9\times 8\times 7\times 6 =30240$ sequences that contain no duplicate. And if a sequence contains no duplicate, the probability that it is in increasing order is $\frac{1}{5!}=\frac{1}{120}$. So the probability is $\frac{30240}{120\cdot 10^5}=\frac{252}{10000}=0.0252$.